# List not spawning multiple enemies Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

would somebody be kind enough to explain why only one enemy is spawning? I created this program and it worked fine with only one enemy, then when appending the enemies to a list with a range of 6, only one is spawning still. I have been trying to fix this forever. Thanks!

```
import os
import pygame
import random
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 700))
enemyamount = 6
enemy1x = []
enemy1y = []
enemy1 = []
enemy1xchange = []
enemy1ychange = []

for i in range(enemyamount):
    enemy1.append(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "enemy1.png")).convert_alpha())
    enemy1x.append(random.randrange(100, 200))
    enemy1y.append(random.randrange(100, 200))
    enemy1xchange.append(.2)
    enemy1ychange.append(.2)


def enemy9(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemy1[i],(x, y))

class Menu():
    def menuFunc(self):
        background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "bg.png")).convert_alpha()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Invaders")
        icon = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("assets", "troll.png")).convert_alpha()
        pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

        inMenu = True
        while inMenu:
            for i in range(enemyamount):
                enemy9(enemy1x[i], enemy1y[i], i)
                if enemy1x[i] <= 230:
                    enemy1x[i] += enemy1xchange[i]
                elif enemy1y[i] <= 550 and enemy1x[i] <= 231:
                    enemy1y[i] += enemy1ychange[i]
                elif enemy1x[i] <= 537:
                    enemy1x[i] += enemy1xchange[i]
                elif enemy1y[i] >= 162 and enemy1x[i] <= 538:
                    enemy1y[i] -= enemy1ychange[i]
                elif enemy1x[i] <= 760:
                    enemy1x[i] += enemy1xchange[i]
                elif enemy1y[i] < 540:
                    enemy1y[i] += enemy1ychange[i]
                elif enemy1x[i] < 1000:
                    enemy1x[i] += enemy1xchange[i]
                if enemy1x[i] > 1000:
                    enemy1x[i] = -50
                    enemy1y[i] = 330

            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            enemy9(enemy1x[i], enemy1y[i], i)
            pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: The posted code depends on your local file structure and three files we don't have.  Can you please remove those dependencies so that we can run your code?  Also, where is the tracing you did to determine how many times you actually spawned enemies, and where?  This is basic debugging we expect with any such question.  You did a nice job of paring down the code; you could do this farther by reducing the `change` actions and using clear variable names (or good comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two of your last three lines of your snippet are responsible:

```
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
enemy9(enemy1x[i], enemy1y[i], i)
pygame.display.update()
```

The first thing you do is clear the canvas and blit the background image over it. These three lines are adjacent to the for-loop in terms of scope, so any drawing you performed in the for-loop/if-statements have no effect, since you just blitted the entire screen. You then invoke `enemy9` with the last value of `i` exactly one time after clearing the screen, so that's why you only see one enemy.

Not sure what your intention was here. The sequence should be, once per frame:

1. Blit the background
2. Iterate over your enemies, draw each one.